# Does Number of commits can affect svn performance

Tags: performance, svn

I was about to commit about 1000 files at once after few refactoring stuff. Is it advisable to commit such huge number of files or I should commit them in batches. I am trying to look at pros and cons sort of.

One of the pros is that I will have same entry in the SVN for all my changes and will be easy to navigate.

Comment: If it's actually one atomic change, then your repo should reflect that.  1000 files is a lot, but nothing subversion can't handle.  If it's actually 3 or 4 refactorings, I would do them all as separate commits.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's not mine.

Comment: @Corbin, I think what you are writing is so important that it should be  an answer, not just a comment: changes that are conceptually one must be committed together and vice versa. It is one of the most important CI best practices.

Comment: @malenkiy_scot Have expanded on it a little bit and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a number of files as small as 1000, I would worry less about performance and more about correct work flow.  1000 files is a lot of files and thus a lot of changes, but Subversion should handle it reasonably well.

However, if all of the changes are not actually 1 change, then it should not be one commit.  For example, if you're renaming 3 functions, I would make each rename a separate commit.  Depending on what specifically you're doing, you may be able to get away with one commit, but a year from now when you're browsing through the logs, you'll make life easier on yourself if you tend to stick to small commits.  If it really is only one change, then one commit is definitely your best option (for example, renaming one function).

Answer (score 1):

SVN can handle 1000 files at once. The only reason to check in batches is to give each batch a different commit message, like "fixed bug #22" and "added flair".

Answer (score 0):

the number of files doesnt really matter.
when you commit changes to your code repo, you should be thinking of build statiblity and test compliance.

*That answers your question*: If you have made changes to n files and only commit some of them, then you're likely to break the build (not even talking abt the tests). So you should commit all necessary files to guarantee build integrity at least.

svn and other tools are well capable of dealing with such nb of files, which will represent a single transaction on the server.